# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'value'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I get an error all the time when I try to save an image and text into my SQL Server database.

Here is my code

```
If confirm("คุณต้องการจะเพิ่มข้อมูลหรือไม่") = vbNo Then Return

        sql = "select count(*) from dataplantaev2 where loc = '" & txt_loc_save.Text & "'"
        If cmd_excuteScalar() > 0 Then
            error_message("ไม่สามารถเพิ่มได้ เนื่องจากมีอยู่แล้วในระบบ")
            Return
        End If

        sql = "insert into dataplantaev2 value(@loc, @sci, @fam, @type, @seri, @loca, @dom, @pic)"
        cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("loc", txt_loc_save.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sci", txt_sci_save.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fam", txt_fam_save.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("type", txt_type_save.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("seri", txt_seri_save.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("loca", txt_loca_save.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dom", txt_dom_save.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pic", convert_PictureBox_toDatabase(PictureBox1))
        If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery > 0 Then
            ok_message("เพิ่มสำเร็จ")
        Else
            error_message("เพิ่มไม่สำเร็จ")

        End If
```

Comment: Why don't you put parameters also in the WHERE statement? This is a big security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try it again. **Values** not **Value**:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO dataplantaev2 VALUES(@loc, @sci, @fam, @type, @seri, @loca, @dom, @pic)"
```

Comment: And add the column names to the INSERT. `INSERT INTO dataplantaev2 (loc, sci, fam, ...) VALUES(@loc, @sci ...)` Otherwise someone is going to rearrange the columns on your table some day and break your app.